# Local Esplora Not Compiling on Clean `new-index` Branch

Tags: compiling, electrum-server

I'm immediately failing to compile https://github.com/Blockstream/electrs on a clean branch of `new-index` as instructed in the README. The build is failing with the following error:

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `librocksdb-sys v6.20.3`

...

electrs/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-3b3cba65ffc3c8e0/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at '"enum_(unnamed_at_rocksdb/include/rocksdb/c_h_854_1)" is not a valid Ident'
```

My variation from the run command in the README.md is in trying to connect to Polar/Regtest data. The command is run based on feedback in related questions and I've verified that the directory exists for me.

`cargo run --release --bin electrs -- -vvvv --daemon-dir ~/.polar/networks/1/volumes/bitcoind/backend1 --network=regtest`

Any feedback on this particular issue would be greatly appreciated as well as any tips on running Esplora on `regtest`, that ideally expand on `--lightmode`.

```
OS: MacOS (Intel)
rustc: 1.72.1
cargo: 1.72.1
rustup: 1.26.0
```

Comment: Seems to be a version conflict between `bindgen` version < 0.62 via `rocksdb`, and `clang` version 15. I was unfortunately planning on using XCode 15 for the same project so this does create a material issue.

Comment: For what it's worth https://github.com/mempool/electrs is a maintained fork which serves the same purpose.

Comment: Its worth a lot! Thank you for responding @AntoinePoinsot

Answer (score 1):

There were several steps I was able to take to resolve this at the expense of the `librocksdb-oldcpu` feature and optional dependency.

1. Remove `librocksdb-oldcpu` dependency and feature
2. Upgrade `librocksdb` to `0.21.0`, this pulls `bindgen` up to `>0.62.0`.
3. Update the Iterator implementation in src/new-index/db.rs to fix a breaking change on the response type of a function.

You can see the commit of my fork for this [here](https://github.com/Blockstream/electrs/commit/d048abae88da77a1138dcea51b5226a3cfb2c7dd).

I understand that this change optimizes for my machine and expediency so still looking for any insights into how others maybe using Electrum in `Regtest` today.